# How do you delete only the duplicates that fulfill another condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

I want to clean up this data-set.Example Table
[image]

It contains many duplicates. I want to delete only the duplicates from the `UUID` column that have the highest value in the column Shape_Area. A loop must be created that detects the duplicates and compares the values from column Area within the found duplicates.

I've tried the `duplicate` function, but I cannot trust that the selected value is the greatest value from column Area.

I want an Output table that includes unique values that have the greatest value in column Area. 
Can anyone help on this one?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, don't post images; rather copy/paste your table in the question, so everybody can use your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `dplyr` package like this

```
library(dplyr)
newdata <- mydata %>% 
    group_by(UUID) %>% 
    arrange(-Shape_Area) %>% 
    slice(1)
```

For each value of `UUID` this code creates a group and then arranges each group with respect to `Shape_Area`. Then only the first row (e.g. the highest value) is selected.

If you want to save this data use this:

```
write.csv(newdata, file = "Output.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! I think it works, but to be sure i Need to Export the Data-set. This Code does not seem to work: write.csv(Data, file = "Output.csv"). It gives out the orginial data-set i imported. How can i define the command, so R knows to Export the result from the command above? (I'm very new to R, so this might be an obvious demand..)

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to save this to csv. Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.